# Angular js : ng-model default value of input is not set in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using ng-model to link input values with model.

If I set default value in input box it does not show in $scope, but If I change anything in this input I can see changes.

```
<input type='text' id="save_quote_email" name="save_quote_email" ng-model="AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails[0].EmailAddress" value="praveend06@gmail.com" />
{{AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails[0].EmailAddress}}
```

I can set this value in controller, then it will work, but such values will come in form when my html loaded.

Comment: using `ng-init` should work

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't use `ng-init` in this case.

From [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. **Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.**

Then, simply do it in your controller:

```
AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails[0].EmailAddress = "praveend06@gmail.com";
```

Comment: I am trying to get input value using document.getElementById("save_quote_email"); in function dtoresource.rc1Step1DTO, but not getting any value.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 ng-init="AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails[0].EmailAddress='praveend06@gmail.com'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-init="AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails[0].EmailAddress='praveend06@gmail.com'"
```

Comment: how is this different from the answer above? you edited your answer altogether!